# Function to search dictionary and display whole entry

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to build a function that will search my dictionary for a value under the key 'Username' and print the whole entry. So if I search for the username ' KKYSD' it will return that username (if it exists, and print the rest of the entry too. This is my current code:

```
def find_user():
    value = input ('Input Username:')
    for k, entry in reviewers_dicts.items():
        if value == entry['Username']: 
            return k, entry   

print(find_user());
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-9140ff50d541> in <module>
      6             return k, entry
      7 
----> 8 print(find_user());

<ipython-input-12-9140ff50d541> in find_user()
      3     value = input ('Input Username:')
      4     for k, entry in reviewers_dicts.items():
----> 5         if value == entry['Username']:
      6             return k, entry
      7 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My file is definitely a dictionary - running `print(type(reviewers_dicts))` proves this.

An issue I have noticed is that when I run:

`print(type(reviewers_dicts['Username']))`

I get:

`<class 'str'>`

I'm guessing this is what's causing my issue, so how would I go about fixing this?

EDIT:

reviewers_dicts=

`{'Username': 'yuoc2324', 'DOB': '02.08.1975', 'State': 'South Dakota', 'Reviewed': []}`

Comment: Show a sample of your "reviewers_dicts" as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your reviewer_dict; your `find_user` function works perfectly out-of-the-box provided reviewer_dict is a dictionary-of-dictionaries. Example:

```py
reviewers_dicts = {1: {'Username': 'tston529', 'Food': 'ramen'}, 2: {'Username': 'shogga22', 'Food': 'pizza'}}
```

The `entries` in your `for k, entry in reviewers_dicts.items():` presently is a list of each value in your main dict, i.e. `['yuoc2324', '02.08.1975', 'South Dakota', []]`, none of which are a dictionary.

Comment: It's meant to be a dictionary of dictionaries but my early code seems to just take the first line of my file and make that the single entry. The code is from a question I asked earlier

Comment: So the issue you're having is with parsing your file, then...?

Comment: Yes, though glad to know my function is good. I used the code ```with open(reviewers_list) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        reviewers_dicts = json.loads(line)
        print(reviewers_dicts)```

Comment: So instead of *assigning* json.loads(line) to reviewer_dicts, *append* json.loads(line) to your dict.Or rather do that **and** make reviewer_dicts an array and tweak your `for..in` a bit to work for arrays rather than dictionaries. Future reference, this seems like crucial info needed in your other question, (and this one?). I guess I'm a bit confused about what you wanted from this question, then...